# C char array to binary file

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, binaryfiles

```
    int felvetel()
{
    FILE *ptr_myfile;
    struct stadion* my_record;

    my_record = malloc(sizeof(struct stadion) * 1);
    ptr_myfile=fopen("test.bin","wb");
    if (!ptr_myfile)
    {
        printf("Nem lehet megnyitni a fajlt!");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("Varos: ");
    scanf("%s", my_record[0].varos);
    printf("Csapat: ");
    scanf("%s", my_record[0].csapat);
    printf("Nezoszam: ");
    scanf("%i", my_record[0].nezoszam);
    printf("Koltseg: ");
    scanf("%i", my_record[0].koltseg);
    printf("Atadas eve: ");
    scanf("%i", my_record[0].ev);
    printf("Atadas honapa: ");
    scanf("%i", my_record[0].honap);
    printf("Atadas napja: ");
    scanf("%i", my_record[0].nap);
    fwrite(my_record, sizeof(struct stadion), 1, ptr_myfile);
    fclose(ptr_myfile);
    return 0;
}
```

It isn't working. When I want to add an int in a 3. line I got "Segmentation fault", but I dont't know why.

And please check, is it good?

```
    int listazas()
{
    FILE *ptr_myfile;
    struct stadion my_record;

    ptr_myfile=fopen("test.bin","rb");
    if (!ptr_myfile)
    {
        printf("Nem lehet megnyitni a fajlt!");
        return 1;
    }
    while (!(feof(ptr_myfile)))
    {
        fread(&my_record,sizeof(struct stadion),1,ptr_myfile);
        printf("%s\t",my_record.varos);
        printf("%s\t",my_record.csapat);
        printf("%i\t",my_record.nezoszam);
        printf("%i\t",my_record.koltseg);
        printf("%i\t",my_record.ev);
        printf("%i\t",my_record.honap);
        printf("%i\t",my_record.nap);
    }
    fclose(ptr_myfile);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope it is working well, but I couldn't try, becaues I don't have anything in my binary file.

Why is it add the struct to binary file two times?

Comment: For integers, `scanf` needs a pointer to the integer, so pass in e.g. `&my_record.nezoszam`.

Comment: what is `struct stadion` ?

Comment: post `struct stadion`

Comment: @dvnrrs also `scanf("%i", &my_record[0].ev);` and `scanf("%i", &my_record[0].honap);` and `scanf("%i", &my_record[0].nap);`. Also, Dear OP, showing  definition of `struct station` would much or helpful than than `listazas`

Comment: Yes, we need to see the struct to make sure you have `char` arrays and not pointers, but i think @dvnrrs is on the money here.

Comment: struct stadion
 {
  char varos[100];
  char csapat[100];
  int nezoszam;
  int koltseg;
  int ev;
  int honap;
  int nap;
 };

Another question. Why is it write this struct to my binary file 2 times?

Comment: my_record = malloc... line gives you a pointer to the first element. struct my_record array[3] also gives you 1 pointer to an array of 3, the only difference is you have "bounds checking". This is why * 3 crashes. You can't make the pointer 3x large.

Comment: @user3457237 Please edit question to include relevant information... so the other people will not have to follow comments, but understand question immediately upon reading it.

Comment: @StephenJ What??  Read the code, please.

Comment: Sorry, I was too busy reading the English: "When I want to add an int in a 3. line I got "